# Creating a spider diagram/mind map with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to implement a "spider diagram" or "mind map" in CSS.

Essentially, what I'd like, is a ring of boxes around a central box.

[image: Spider diagram]

Ideally, these would all just be DIVs that I could add more/less content to as I saw fit (and, hopefully, manipulate using JS). They don't need to be draggable or anything like that.

Unlike the diagram, they don't need to have the grey lines etc. from the outer topics to the name of the mind map - I'm really not bothered about that.

Firstly, I really don't know where to start. I guess I'd have to use absolute positioning for each box? That probably wouldn't be too bad if my audience were using the same resolution and browser but that won't always be the case.

So, my real question is, how do I set up DIVs like these that will stay in the same place on different resolutions and in different browsers? Can I use absolute positioning within a relatively-aligned DIV or something?

The browsers I need to support primarily are IE10, Chrome and Safari. So I guess I should be designing for IE10 as a base?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create fixed width / height div and place other divs there.

```
<div style='width: 1000px; height: 1000px; position: relative;'>
    <div class='note' style='position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;'></div>
    <div class='note' style='position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 150px;'></div>
    <div class='note' style='position: absolute; left: 350px; top: 350px;'></div>
</div>
```

Since wrapper is constant width, so inner elements will stay in same position, no matter of browser window size.

Comment: It also works with `%` for `width, left, right, bottom` and `top` so you can make sure it occupies a full screen and stay at the same relative position whatever the size (you might have overlap of the inside divs on small screens however), you just have to fix the height.

Comment: @Math as you say - it may overlap each other, and that is not desired effect.

Comment: That's why I did not propose it as an answer, simply as an alternative since some people (like me) do not like to create pages with fixed length. And the overlap can be prevented if we have access to small screen.